# Please help me to figure out Array concat() method and write pure Javascript code

Tags: javascript

Please help me to figure out Array concat() method and write pure Javascript code.
This is the code from ECMA-262 standard

1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
2. Let A be ? ArraySpeciesCreate(O, 0).
3. Let n be 0.
4. Let items be a List whose first element is O and whose subsequent elements 
   are, in left to right order, the
    arguments that were passed to this function invocation.
5. Repeat, while items is not empty

   a. Remove the first element from items and let E be the value of the element.

   b. Let spreadable be ? IsConcatSpreadable(E).

   c. If spreadable is true, then

   ```
      i. Let k be 0.

      ii. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(E, "length" "length")).

      iii. If n + len > 253-1, throw a TypeError exception.

      iv. Repeat, while k < len
          1. Let P be ! ToString(k).
          2. Let exists be ? HasProperty(E, P).
          3. If exists is true, then
             a. Let subElement be ? Get(E, P).
             b. Perform ? CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(A, ! ToString(n), subElement).
          4. Increase n by 1.
          5. Increase k by 1.
   ```

   d. Else E is added as a single item rather than spread,

   ```
     i. If n≥253-1, throw a TypeError exception.

     ii. Perform ? CreateDataPropertyOrThrow(A, ! ToString(n), E).

     iii. Increase n by 1.
   ```
6. Perform ? Set(A, "length" "length", n, true).
7. Return A.

I would like to have code like this.

Array.prototype.con = function(){

```
  let 0 = ; 
  let A = ;
  let n = 0;
  let item = ;
  so on...
```

}

let arr1 = [1,2];

let arr2 = [3,4];

arr1.con(arr2) //receive effect like concat()

Comment: I don't understand a thing about your question

Comment: I would like to create my own method, that will work like concat() method, also I want to understand how  concat() method works under the Standard.

Comment: You seem to have all the steps from the ECMA-262 Standard. Try converting these to code and see what happens.

Comment: DTul please help me to convert it.

Comment: @Vigen Stackoverflow isn't a place where people just write code for you. Try it yourself and if you run into problems then ask a specific question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you, here is the specific question. How to convert 4 step (4. Let items be a List whose first element is O and whose subsequent elements are, in left to right order, the arguments that were passed to this function invocation.) into javascript code?

Comment: Please edit your question to the specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your question in the comments. You can access items by calling `this` in your prototype function. It refers to the actual instance you are calling on.

`items = this;`

```js
Array.prototype.newTest = function(toBeAdded){
  console.log('this', this);
  console.log('To be Added', toBeAdded);
}

const arr = ['foo', 'bar'];

arr.newTest(['x','y']);
```